# Hide RelativeLayout when pull ScrollView

Tags: android

I have RelativeLayoutin top Scroll View, and now i want when pull down RelativeLayoutin hint and pull up RelativeLayoutin show.
How i do?
My xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Rlayout_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Rlayout_top"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
private float lastPosition=0;
    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                int scrollY = rootScrollView.getScrollY(); //for verticalScrollView

               if(scrollY >lastPosition){
            // hide your RelativeLayout
            }else {
            //show your view

            }
    lastPosition=scrollY
        });
```

Comment: ý em là cứ scroll up là hiện,scroll down là gone đi đúng ko ? vậy xem lại a edit

Comment: Vâng a. e code theo nhưng mà lúc mình di chuyển scroll rồi giữ nó thì cái Rlayout_top đấy nó cứ hide show liên tục ( như đèn nháy ấy :v). có cách nào khắc phục ko a?

Comment: để nó đỡ nháy e phải để sao cho scroll 1 đoạn nhất định mới hide/show view,em thu thay  nhu sau số 25 là a fix, e thử xem khoảng cách  nào là hợp lí :
  if(scrollY >(lastPosition +25)){
            // hide your RelativeLayout
            }else   if(scrollY <(lastPosition -25)) {
            //show your view

            }

Comment: E làm được r ạ. Em set ontouchlistener cho nó rồi làm cũng tương tự cái này.
https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-AutoHideMenu